# React modal is not working when call in function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, modal-dialog

I have a modal that I want to open in useffect here is the my code in carvin function console.log working but modal didn't popup. I have made one main component as Loyaltycash and calling carvin in useeffect

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
export default function Loyaltychash(props) {
  const { show, handlemodalloyalty, contractid } = props;


  useEffect(() => {
    if (contractid != "") {
      getdata();
      setLoading(true);
      carvin();
    }
  }, [show]);
  


  return (
    <div>
    </div>
  );
}
function carvin() {
  console.log("innnn");
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Modal show={true}>
          <Modal.Header>
            
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button variant="secondary">Close</Button>
            <Button variant="primary">Save Changes</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using show={true} for all time

```
<Modal show={show}>
```

and

```
return (
    <div>
{carvin()}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: I want to open open that is in carvin function. In Loyaltychash there is another modal that is handle by using show

Comment: you should call carvin function to show that

Comment: Is there any way top open modal with calling it in return

Comment: `return (
    <div>
{carvin()}
    </div>
  );`